# hoverIntent not executing properly in nav menu

Tags: jquery, css, hoverintent

Ok, I have this navigation menu that works in general. When using the hoverIntent plugin, the nav menu has problems when moving from far left tab menu item to the far right tab menu item. As you mouseover each menu item, the dropdown menu for that menu item sometimes displays on time when you mouseover and sometimes it doesn't. You have to mouseover multiple times over a main menu item to get the dropdown menu to display. Here is the hoverIntent code being used.

```
$("#nav-main-list li").hoverIntent({
over: makeTall, 
timeout: 300, 
sensitivity: 20,
interval: 150,
out: makeShort
});
// Hover intent over function
function makeTall(){
$('.subnav:eq(0)', this ).show();
if(!($(this).children('a').hasClass('home')))
{ 
//$(this).addClass("snavhover");
$(this).children().addClass("snavhover");        
}      
}
// Hover intent out function
function makeShort(){
$('.subnav').hide();
if(!($(this).children().hasClass('home')))
{
//$(this).css("background", "none").css("color", "#1E598E");     
$(this).children().removeClass("snavhover"); 
}
}
```